Why does unity UI X+Y position need to add numbers?
For some reason, to set UI element's x + y coordinates, I have to add large numbers to the code. For Y, this code sets it to -450, and the x to 128*ui slot, yet the numbers I have had to input are far different. Is there any way around this?
`using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Hotbar_Selection : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float hotbarSlot = 1;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        setSlot();
        transform.position = new Vector3((((hotbarSlot - 5) * 128) + 960), 90);
    }

    private void setSlot()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))
        {
            hotbarSlot = 1;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2))
        {
            hotbarSlot = 2;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha3))
        {
            hotbarSlot = 3;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha4))
        {
            hotbarSlot = 4;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha5))
        {
            hotbarSlot = 5;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha6))
        {
            hotbarSlot = 6;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha7))
        {
            hotbarSlot = 7;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha8))
        {
            hotbarSlot = 8;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha9))
        {
            hotbarSlot = 9;
        }
    }
}
`

These numbers work, but can I do it an easier way?

This is intended behaviour. One unity unit = one pixel in Unity's UI sysyem, so 128 seems pretty reasonable.

UI moves in screen pixel space if the Canvas is set to Screenspace Overlay. If you rather want to use the values you see in the Inspector then use RectTransform.anchoredPosition instead which takes the anchor and pivot settings into account as well.

in general I wouldn't poll and set the position every frame but only when an input occurs. Canvas UI updates might cause re-layout which is quite expensive.
You could just simplify this into something like e.g.
public class Hotbar_Selection : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float hotbarSlot = 1;

    [SerializeField] private RectTransform rectTransform;

    private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<KeyCode, int> keyCodeValues = new Dictionary<KeyCode, int>()
    {
        { KeyCode.Alpha1, 1 },
        { KeyCode.Alpha2, 2 },
        { KeyCode.Alpha3, 3 },
        { KeyCode.Alpha4, 4 },
        { KeyCode.Alpha5, 5 },
        { KeyCode.Alpha6, 6 },
        { KeyCode.Alpha7, 7 },
        { KeyCode.Alpha8, 8 },
        { KeyCode.Alpha9, 9 }
    };

    void Awake()
    {
        if(!rectTransform) rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        GetSlotInput();
    }

    private void GetSlotInput()
    {
        foreach(var kvp in keyCodeValues)
        {
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(kvp.Key))
            {
                ApplySlot(kvp.Value);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void ApplySlot(int index)
    {
        // if you don't even need this as an exposed class field you can get rid of it
        hotbarSlot = index;
        rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector3(((hotbarSlot - 5) * 128 + 960), 90);
    }
}

